# Can a subshell create a subprocess?

Tags: linux, subshell

So if I input the command like below, a sub-process (`PID 4920`) is created by the subshell.

```
linuxprobe@DESKTOP-TP0G72N:~$ (sleep 2;ps -f --forest;sleep 5)
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
linuxpr+     513     512  0 Feb17 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
linuxpr+    4920     513  0 01:35 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ -bash
linuxpr+    4922    4920  0 01:35 pts/0    00:00:00      \_ ps -f --forest
```

If I input the command like below, seems no sub-process is created

```
linuxprobe@DESKTOP-TP0G72N:~$ (ps -f --forest)
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
linuxpr+     513     512  0 Feb17 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
linuxpr+    5511     513  0 01:45 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ ps -f --forest
```

Why can subshell create a sub-process in the first example?

Answer (score 10):

It's not a matter of can; both, as you can see, do create a subprocess.

The difference is the in the second case, the last command in the shell is the ps execution.

And because nothing happens after that, your bash decides that instead of exec'ing in a forked process, it can just exec the ps executable in itself, without fork'ing before.

So, not a matter of *can*, but a matter of *choose not to*, to optimize.

Comment: This is very similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call